Redirecting To Backend Service in API Management After Authorization
I have an Azure API management in which i have attached a flask service,in that service there is an GET api which is returning some json.
Now i am recieving Bearer token in api call and i am validating(IN the inbound request of API) that token with the secret in my key vault ,till this everything is fine but i am not getting the json response
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <!-- Extract the Bearer token from the Authorization header -->
        <set-variable name="Bearer Token" value="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization", "").Substring(7))" />
        <!-- Retrieve the secret from Key Vault -->
        <set-variable name="KeyVaultSecret" value="{{secret}}" />
        <!-- Check if both the Bearer token and the Key Vault secret are strings and have the same length -->
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Variables["Bearer Token"] is string && context.Variables["KeyVaultSecret"] is string && ((string)context.Variables["Bearer Token"]).Length == ((string)context.Variables["KeyVaultSecret"]).Length)">
                <!-- Compare the Bearer token with the Key Vault secret -->
                <choose>
                    <!-- <when condition="@(context.Variables["Bearer Token"] == context.Variables["KeyVaultSecret"])">
                        <return-response>
                            <set-status code="200" reason="OK" />
                            <set-body>Bearer token matches the secret.</set-body>
                        </return-response>
                    </when> -->
                    <when condition="@($"{context.Variables["Bearer Token"]}" == $"{context.Variables["KeyVaultSecret"]}")">
                        <return-response>
                            <set-status code="200" reason="OK" />
                            <set-body>Bearer token matches the Key vault Secret.</set-body>
                        </return-response>
                    </when>
                    <otherwise>
                        <return-response>
                            <set-status code="401" reason="Unauthorized" />
                            <set-body>@($"Bearer token does not matches the secret. Bearer Token: {context.Variables["Bearer Token"]}, Key Vault Secret: {context.Variables["KeyVaultSecret"]}/5")</set-body>
                        </return-response>
                    </otherwise>
                </choose>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <return-response>
                    <set-status code="400" reason="Bad Request" />
                    <set-body>@($"Bearer token does not matches the secret. Bearer Token: {context.Variables["Bearer Token"]}, Key Vault Secret: {context.Variables["KeyVaultSecret"]}")</set-body>
                </return-response>
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>

This is my inbound policy
I am getting Bearer token matches the Key vault Secret.
But not the json associated with this api

You are not getting expected JSON response from backend because your policy is returning a custom response after the token validation instead of forwarding the request to backend. So, modify your policy as given below.
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-variable name="BearerToken" value="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization", "").Substring(7))" />
        <set-variable name="KeyVaultSecret" value="{{secret}}" />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Variables["BearerToken"] is string && context.Variables["KeyVaultSecret"] is string && ((string)context.Variables["BearerToken"]).Length == ((string)context.Variables["KeyVaultSecret"]).Length)">
                <!-- Compare the Bearer token with the Key Vault secret -->
                <choose>
                    <when condition="@($"{context.Variables["BearerToken"]}" == $"{context.Variables["KeyVaultSecret"]}")">
                        <!-- Token matches, allow request to proceed -->
                    </when>
                    <otherwise>
                        <return-response>
                            <set-status code="401" reason="Unauthorized" />
                            <set-body>Bearer token does not match the secret.</set-body>
                        </return-response>
                    </otherwise>
                </choose>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <return-response>
                    <set-status code="400" reason="Bad Request" />
                    <set-body>Invalid Bearer token or secret format.</set-body>
                </return-response>
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>

You need not to use <return-response> after the token validation.

It's working completely fine
thanks

@Ikhtesam Afrin i have another question related to this
i am sending data via body in raw form but this api is returning
{
"error": "missing request json"
}

@Ashu You can create a new question as the primary requirement of this question has been addressed
